# Swin-Transformer-TF not working with generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, transformer-model, swin-transformer

Swin-Transformer-TF from https://github.com/rishigami/Swin-Transformer-TF/tree/main, failed when I use generator for train. I tried many generators, and many output of generators options, lists, Tensor's etc. everything is crashing.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
!git clone https://github.com/rishigami/Swin-Transformer-TF.git
import sys
sys.path.append('./Swin-Transformer-TF')
from swintransformer import SwinTransformer
```

create the model:

```
img_adjust_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda data: tf.keras.applications.imagenet_utils.preprocess_input(tf.cast(data, 
                                                                                                                     tf.float32), 
                                                                                                             mode="torch"), 
                                          input_shape=[224, 224,3])
pretrained_model = SwinTransformer('swin_tiny_224', num_classes=2, 
                                   include_top=True, pretrained=0, 
                                   use_tpu=0)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    img_adjust_layer,
    pretrained_model,
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])
    
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5, epsilon=1e-8),
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
model.summary()
```

Train the model, without generetor, works.

```
x_train = np.zeros((20,224,224,3))
y_train = np.zeros((20,2))
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
         steps_per_epoch=2, epochs=1)
```

Adding a generator (and I tried a few), crashes. The shape is read as `(None,None,None,3)`:

```
def __data_generation():
    for i in range(3000):
      yield np.zeros((20,224,224,3)),np.zeros((20,2))
gen=__data_generation()
x,y=next(gen)
print(x.shape,y.shape)
model.fit(gen, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=4)



AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-fb53f3a3d1ae> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 x,y=next(gen)
      6 print(x.shape,y.shape)
----> 7 model.fit(gen, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=4)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

/content/./Swin-Transformer-TF/swintransformer/model.py in tf__call(self, x)
      8                 do_return = False
      9                 retval_ = ag__.UndefinedReturnValue()
---> 10                 x = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).forward_features, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)
     11 
     12                 def get_state():

/content/./Swin-Transformer-TF/swintransformer/model.py in tf__forward_features(self, x)
      8                 do_return = False
      9                 retval_ = ag__.UndefinedReturnValue()
---> 10                 x = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).patch_embed, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)
     11 
     12                 def get_state():

/content/./Swin-Transformer-TF/swintransformer/model.py in tf__call(self, x)
      9                 retval_ = ag__.UndefinedReturnValue()
     10                 (B, H, W, C) = ag__.converted_call(ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(x).get_shape, (), None, fscope).as_list, (), None, fscope)
---> 11                 assert ag__.and_(lambda : ag__.ld(H) == ag__.ld(self).img_size[0], lambda : ag__.ld(W) == ag__.ld(self).img_size[1]), f"Input image size ({ag__.ld(H)}*{ag__.ld(W)}) doesn't match model ({ag__.ld(self).img_size[0]}*{ag__.ld(self).img_size[1]})."
     12                 x = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).proj, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)
     13                 x = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).reshape, (ag__.ld(x),), dict(shape=[-1, ag__.ld(H) // ag__.ld(self).patch_size[0] * (ag__.ld(W) // ag__.ld(self).patch_size[0]), ag__.ld(self).embed_dim]), fscope)

AssertionError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filegq78ow1y.py", line 10, in tf__call
        x = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).forward_features, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)
    File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filehkbim9xc.py", line 10, in tf__forward_features
        x = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).patch_embed, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)
    File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_file3nqntnhc.py", line 11, in tf__call
        assert ag__.and_(lambda : ag__.ld(H) == ag__.ld(self).img_size[0], lambda : ag__.ld(W) == ag__.ld(self).img_size[1]), f"Input image size ({ag__.ld(H)}*{ag__.ld(W)}) doesn't match model ({ag__.ld(self).img_size[0]}*{ag__.ld(self).img_size[1]})."

    AssertionError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'swin_tiny_224' (type SwinTransformerModel).
    
    in user code:
    
        File "/content/./Swin-Transformer-TF/swintransformer/model.py", line 422, in call  *
            x = self.forward_features(x)
        File "/content/./Swin-Transformer-TF/swintransformer/model.py", line 411, in forward_features  *
            x = self.patch_embed(x)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler  **
            raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
        File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_file3nqntnhc.py", line 11, in tf__call
            assert ag__.and_(lambda : ag__.ld(H) == ag__.ld(self).img_size[0], lambda : ag__.ld(W) == ag__.ld(self).img_size[1]), f"Input image size ({ag__.ld(H)}*{ag__.ld(W)}) doesn't match model ({ag__.ld(self).img_size[0]}*{ag__.ld(self).img_size[1]})."
    
        AssertionError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'patch_embed' (type PatchEmbed).
        
        in user code:
        
            File "/content/./Swin-Transformer-TF/swintransformer/model.py", line 336, in call  *
                assert H == self.img_size[0] and W == self.img_size[1],             f"Input image size ({H}*{W}) doesn't match model ({self.img_size[0]}*{self.img_size[1]})."
        
            AssertionError: Input image size (None*None) doesn't match model (224*224).
        
        
        Call arguments received by layer 'patch_embed' (type PatchEmbed):
          • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=float32)
    
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'swin_tiny_224' (type SwinTransformerModel):
      • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` should help in this case, when working with generators. Modified code snippet:

```py
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 


def __data_generation():
    for i in range(20):
      yield np.zeros((20,224,224,3)),np.zeros((20,2))

# Directly using the generator doesn't work
# gen=__data_generation()
# x,y=next(gen)
# print(x.shape,y.shape)

# Try wrapping it in tf.data pipeline
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    __data_generation, 
    output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,224,224,3), dtype=tf.float32), 
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,2,), dtype=tf.float32),
    )
)
x, y = next(iter(ds))
print("Shapes: ", x.shape, y.shape)  # Shapes:  (20, 224, 224, 3) (20, 2)

model.fit(ds, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=4)
```

Moreover, if the generator outputs single image-label pairs (shape `(224,224,3), (2,)`) instead of batching them already (e.g. shape `(20,224,224,3), (20,2)` where batch size is 20), we can use `ds.batch()` to set the batch size before calling `fit()`:

```py
def __data_generation():
    for i in range(20):
      yield np.zeros((224,224,3)),np.zeros((2,))

# Try wrapping it in tf.data pipeline
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    __data_generation, 
    output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(224,224,3), dtype=tf.float32), 
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.float32),
    )
)
ds = ds.batch(2)  # batch size = 2

model.fit(ds, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=4)
```

More guidelines to `tf.data` can be found in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data).

Comment: Unfortunatly it's not working as well. The error is slightly different but still the issue is with the shapes: ... all arguments received by layer 'swin_tiny_224' (type SwinTransformerModel):
      • x=tf.Tensor(shape=<unknown>, dtype=float32)

Comment: @NaomiFridman I updated the answer, hopefully it works this time. I'll also add some steps for batching in a moment.

Comment: Updated again :)

Comment: This version works perfectly. Thanks